# Regex for age validation that accepts an age between 0-200 using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that allows users to enter only numbers  between 0 and 200.
I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var age_regex=/^\S[0-9]{0,3}$/;
```

Comment: `dose not work` - This is of no use. Please include what the actual problem is.

Comment: this won't actually need a regex.

Comment: @vks - How many years old is a two-month old baby? Vilas - what is the `\S` for in your regex?

Comment: \S will not allows space at first in textbox and I will also consider baby age so suggest me regex for age validation (I used 0 for baby).

Comment: @VilasGalave you mean it is people? If you are validating input, do you get user to re-confirm?

Comment: @VilasGalave That is not the correct way to use RegEx. Try my answer below.

Comment: @nnnnnn 2 month === 0 years... Lol....a baby of 0 years of age....

Comment: Regex could be proper in more advanced cases (like distinguishing numbers signifying age vs other numbers) but in this paricular case it clearly is not the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of regex, you can compare numerical value itself:

```
var ageValue = 50; // get the input age here
var ageNumericVal = +ageValue;
if (ageNumericVal < 0 || ageNumericVal > 200) {
  // invalid
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend using an `if` statement for this since regex is not efficient for this case.

Anyway, if you really want to use RegEx, try the following:

```
var age_regex=/\s[0-1]{1}[0-9]{0,2}/;
```

[Regex demo and explanation.](https://www.regex101.com/r/nT5mX5/3)

**EDIT:**

Using this regex in `<input>`:

**(Working Demo)**

```css
p{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  Enter Age: <input type="text" name="number" pattern="[0-1]{1}[0-9]{0,2}" title="Please enter a valid number between 0 and 200.">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>This form will give error if number does not pass the regex.</p>
```

Comment: `\S` will match any non-space character.

Comment: `\s` matches any space character.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I belive OP had it for a reason.

Comment: @IoannisTsiokos which browser are you using? I just tried it in Chrome and it worked - try input 300 and hit submit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][1-9][1-9]|200)$
```

An easy fix to check age would be not to use regex and simply check like this:

```
if(age >= 0 &&  age <= 200)  
{
   //code
}
```

Comment: @nnnnnn:- Already removed that part after watching your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could simply check in `if` condition without need for regex, as:

```
if( input >=0 && input <= 200 ) {
    //its valid
}
```