# HTML numeric input using Reactive forms is showing required validator error instead of Invalid pattern

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, numeric-textbox

I am working on an Angular 8 application and following reacting forms approach. Facing an issue with numeric text box and copying a sample code below.

Typescript:

```
this.sampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            age: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]]
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="number" formControlName="age" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.age.errors }" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.age.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.age.errors.required">Age is required</div>
                             <div *ngIf="f.age.errors.pattern">invalid age value</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Sample Input value:

**'-035040958094385-3443-4355'**

Expected Validation error:

**'invalid age value'**

Actual validation error:

**'Age is required'**

Comment: be carefull, the control when you defined in .ts is **A**ge and the form in .html **a**ge (Angular is case-sensitive).

Comment: Sure..It's sample code.But the actual issue is numeric textbox not showing pattern matching error.

Comment: I make a stackblitz witth your code, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zp5uqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, check if you get any error in console in your code (take account that if if you put "number" the value is null if you write a string)

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for the sample code. But it's always throwing invalid error irrespective of Regex. Eg: for the input 100, its showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp should look like this: It will accept age between 1 and 200. Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29467126/2050306) answer.

```
age: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][1-9][1-9]|200)")]]
```

Check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajc8rq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

you need to put all the **Validators** in array

```
Age: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]]
```

instead of

```
Age: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/')]
```

Comment: Ahh..Sorry that was a typo error. But the issue is still there.

Comment: hmm, is f a getter property ?? if yes give me the code of the property

Comment: Am just trying to use a numeric textbox and the problem is, it's not throwing pattern matching error. Is it the default behavior?

Comment: yeah, according to your regex format the value -035040958094385-3443-4355 doesn't match the format, to test your pattern (regex) go to https://regexr.com/ and pass /^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/ in the expression input and test whatever kind of inputs

Comment: so your regex format prevents a user from inserting values starting with 0 and at least 2 digits, so if you try to insert '-' you won't get any error

Comment: Thanks, But the problem here is, it wont throw any pattern matching error.

Comment: I solved the issue, just remove / from the pattern. for more info check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392373/angular-2-validators-pattern-not-working

Comment: Great..This was the core issue I believe.Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

Check this stackblitz.. this way you can solve problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9j46z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks..Could you please give me a sample which is showing pattern matching error using html numeric input?