# Regex to exclude a range of numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to exclude all decimal numbers below `200`. For example:

```
50.123 invalid
150.103 invalid
205.111 valid
```

With the `([0-9][0-9])|(1[0-9][0-9])\.*` reg expression, I am getting the following results:

```
50.123 valid but should be invalid
150.103 invalid
205.111 valid
```

Can anyone tell me why any decimal number < 100 is valid?

Comment: 200.* is currently invalid with the above regex, which is correct. the problem is anything below 100 is also invalid when it should be valid

Comment: You may use: `^[01]?[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Your regex has a bug: it ends with `\.*` but should end with `\..*` or more precisely `\.\d*`. Your regex requires input to end with any number of dots, rather than a dot then any number of chars/digits.

Comment: @anubhava I edited my initial post to try an make it more easy to understand. thank you for the replies!

Comment: Are you trying to validate numbers between `100` and `200` only?

Comment: @anubhava I am trying to exclude all numbers below 200 (e.g. 0-199 should be invalid). Although, my first regex was showing 0-99 as valid and 100-199 as invalid, when every number below 200 should be invalid. Hope that clears up the confusion

Comment: @anubhava yes your regex works perfecly for me, thank you for your help

Comment: People voting on removal, [please read this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/10844#10844). **Should duplicates be deleted?** In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for age validation that accepts an age between 0-200 using Javascript only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467075/regex-for-age-validation-that-accepts-an-age-between-0-200-using-javascript-only)

Comment: That is not the right dupe as OP is also trying to validate digits after decimal  point here and this question is not tagged as Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the answers (which all work correctly).

Bohemian was also correct in saying that:

> it ends with `\.*` but should end with `\..*` or more precisely `\.\d*`

So I edited my  regular expression to the following which now works fine:

`([0-9][0-9]\.\d*)|(1[0-9][0-9]\.\d*)`

Comment: Does 05.111 in 205.111 match this regex ?

Comment: @LongNguyễnThành using this regex - 05.111 is invalid and 205.111 is valid, which is correct

Comment: But it will also make `00.` and `100.` valid

Answer (score 8):

You may use this regex to validate all your numbers below `200`:

```sh
^[01]?[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8aCZ5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[01]?`: Match `0` or `1` or nothing
- `[0-9]{1,2}`: Match 1 or 2 digits
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)?`: Optionally match `.` followed by 1+ digits
- `$`: End

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the fact you want to **exclude** numbers below 200 and your sample data that showed invalid examples, I think you would need:

```
^(?:[2-9]\d{2,}|1\d{3,})(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fem5Ts/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?:` - 1st Non-capture group:

  - `[2-9]\d{2,}` - Match number ranging from 2-9 followed 2+ digits.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `1\d{3,}` - A 1 followed by at 3+ digits.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

  - `\.\d+` - A literal dot followed by 1+ digits.
  - `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Answer (score 4):

```
/(?<!\d)
(\d{2}|1\d{2})\.\d+/g
```

\d{2}: 2 digits

(?<!\d): not have a digit before it => avoid 05.111 in 205.111 being matched

I tried your regex but it has problems,so I came up with another solution.